# Dwolla guest checkout does not appear when allowFundingSources=True

Tags: dwolla

When using Python for the Dwolla off-site gateway the guest checkout does not always appear as expected. (using reflector account and LIVE. 
When adding products as:

```
Dwolla.add_gateway_product('A Fee 1', 1.05, 'Test product',1)
Dwolla.add_gateway_product('A Fee 2', 1.25, 'Another Test product', 2)
url = Dwolla.get_gateway_URL(destination_number, OrderID, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00,   
'Description',redirectURL, True)
```

**Note True here is for the "allow funding sources"

Total = $3.55 and the guest checkout shows up as expected.

However without changing the settings in the gateway url adding items that total 1092.99 causes the guest checkout to fail to appear.

This is reproducible so does anyone @Dwolla know if there is a dollar limit for when the guest checkout appears and when it does not? Or other reasons for this behavior?

I can provide screen shots of the results but Stackoverflow is not allowing me to attach images yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guest Checkout feature has a transaction amount **limit of $1000.00**, which is why the guest checkout option doesn't appear at the off-site gateway when you try to checkout with a total of $1092.99.

Comment: Thank you. Confirmation is always good.  It should be interesting to see how Dwolla handles this limit when retail, or other industries want guest checkout beyond that limit.